# Phonebook program doesn't work in Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a program that acts like a Phonebook. I have my Contacts written in a text file. My program should read the contacts in the text file, and also also allow the user to add a contact and remove a contact. By doing this it should also update the text file.
So here's my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactListDriver
{
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
{
    File inputFile = new File("C:/Users/Gab Real/workspace/CSc121/MyContacts.txt");
    //System.out.println(String.format("File.canWrite() says %s", inputFile.canWrite()));

    //System.out.println(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());  
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    BufferedReader reader2 = null;
    BufferedReader reader3 = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    File tempFile = new File("temp1.txt");
    try{
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    out = new PrintWriter(tempFile);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = "";

    System.out.println("oooooooooooooooooooooo[Instructions]ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
    System.out.println("o use command 'add' to add a contact (e.g. add Gabrielle 2548-5878-555) o");
    System.out.println("o use command 'remove' + the name of the contact to remove a Contact  o");
    System.out.println("o use command 'exit' to exit the program                              o");
    System.out.println("ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");

    while(!word.contentEquals("exit")){
    System.out.println("\nEnter a command: ");
    word = scan.nextLine();
    String entries[] = word.split(" ");


    if(word.startsWith("add")){
        out.append(entries[1] + " " + entries[2]);
        //out.println(out.toString());
        //out.write("\r\n");
    } else if (word.contains("remove")){
        String currentLine;
        while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
            String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
            if(trimmedLine.contains(entries[1])) continue;
            out.println(currentLine);
        }
    } else if (word.contains("show")){
        String currentLine;
        while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
            System.out.println(currentLine); 
        }
    }
}


    }
    finally {
        out.close();
        reader.close();
        }

  }
}
```

The problems that I encountered as as follows:

1. Some times when I add a contact the text file gets empty after exiting the program.
2. I can only show/remove a contact once. It doesn't allow me to show the contacts many times or delete multiple contacts.

Comment: Do you want to read input from console or file?

Comment: the initial inputs are in the text file @kamoor1982 but the added contacts is in the console..

Comment: Regarding - 'The file emptying after adding', you have totally empty file? or file containing only new contact (& no old)

Comment: @Playmaker yes.. only the added contact is in the file.

Comment: Also, I hope that's not your real phone number.. if yes, I advise you to replace it with some garbage number while you're posting on the forum

Comment: Regarding only added contact -> Why are you writing in a separate temp file? ---- Regarding phone number (see the use "command 'add'" line example)

Comment: @Playmaker.. haha what do u mean? i haven't posted my number :D

Comment: can you help me fix/reprogram it? please.. i really don't know what to do. :'( i keep on modifying and modifying my code but i still don't get it.. :'( i've been scouring the internet for solutions but no luck

Comment: @Playmaker plsss. :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix both your issues..

I've made a number of changes to the code, so it will be difficult to explain everything, but I've included the main points after the code. Try going through it and add a comment in case of any doubt.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactListDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        File inputFile = new File("C:/Users/Gab Real/workspace/CSc121/MyContacts.txt");
        //System.out.println(String.format("File.canWrite() says %s", inputFile.canWrite()));

        //System.out.println(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());  
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        BufferedReader reader2 = null;
        BufferedReader reader3 = null;
        FileWriter out = null;
        String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        //File tempFile = new File("temp1.txt");
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String word = "";

            System.out.println("oooooooooooooooooooooo[Instructions]ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
            System.out.println("o use command 'show' to show all contacts                             o");
            System.out.println("o use command 'add' to add a contact (e.g. add Gabrielle 25485878555) o");
            System.out.println("o use command 'remove' + the name of the contact to remove a Contact  o");
            System.out.println("o use command 'exit' to exit the program                              o");
            System.out.println("ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");

            while (!word.contentEquals("exit")) {
                System.out.println("\nEnter a command: ");
                word = scan.nextLine();
                String entries[] = word.split(" ");

                if (entries[0].equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
                    out = new FileWriter(inputFile, true);
                    out.write(ls + entries[1] + " " + entries[2]);
                    out.flush();
                    //out.println(out.toString());
                    //out.write("\r\n");
                } else if (entries[0].equalsIgnoreCase("remove")) {
                    String allLines = "";
                    String currentLine;
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));

                    while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        allLines = allLines + "|" + currentLine;
                    }
                    String[] allLinesArr = allLines.split("\\|");

                    out = new FileWriter(inputFile, false);
                    for (int i = 0; i < allLinesArr.length; i++) {
                        currentLine = allLinesArr[i];
                        if (currentLine.contains(entries[1])) {
                            System.out.println("Deleting " + entries[1]);
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (i == 0) {
                            out.write(currentLine);
                        } else {
                            out.write(ls + currentLine);
                        }
                    }
                    out.flush();
                } else if (entries[0].equalsIgnoreCase("show")) {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
                    String currentLine;
                    while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
                        System.out.println(currentLine);
                    }
                }
            }

        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Main points to note:**

- The 2nd parameter (true/false) in PrintWriter denotes whether to append (true) or overwrite (false)
- BufferedReader is declared inside functions so that it restarts reading from file start (solving your show multiple times problem)
- PrintWriter in 'remove' is mid-way because, on its declaration, the file will be emptied (hence I have first taken it's contents into a '|' delimited String)

Only the *multiple-remove part is left.* The logic to do that will be to allow the user to enter multiple names separated by " " (hence populating your entries array) & inside the remove bit, looping over it for the array length (from index = 1 to index = entries.length) and putting the if condition inside it.

*Note:* I'm not sure whether the if conditions I've put inside the finally block are necessary. But its safer to keep it there.

Comment: Still working on it.. Understood 2nd issue - and found the cause (Reader reached last line and then has nowhere to go.. - it doesn't reset to line1). Give me 10 mins and I'll fix it :)

Comment: issue 1 is solve but it doesn't print the added contacts into a new line.. it just prints in a single line

Comment: Yeah. Just fixing that

Comment: with regards to issue number 2.. i want the program to remove/delete a contact in the text file.. but it doesn;t allow me to remove or delete multiple contacts.. it should also have a method to show all the current contacts in the file

Comment: You're very welcome.. Stuck on the remove line.. giving little issue.. brb

Comment: okay.. i'll try to fix this as well while waiting.. :) thank you again :)

Comment: Good. Check the new code. And be more careful of your phone number on public forums later on :P

Comment: Hahaha, i forgot that i typed my number on the example. hahaha. i'll be careful next time.. thank you very much .. i'll run through the code :)

Comment: Oh my GOD! It works!!! Thank you thank you very much! :D I don't know what to say.. Thank you for your help really..

Comment: i wish i could give ur answer a million Up votes.. but couldn't even make 1.. haha my reputation is to low. Lol XD

Comment: but there's one issue thought.. whenever i delete a contact.. there is a blank space in the text file.. for example.. if i have 5 contacts in five lines.. i delete 1.. it is removed but there are still 5 lines but 1 is blank..

Comment: but other than that it really work great.. thank you! i want to be a better programmer someday.. :) probably become like you.. :D

Comment: Haha. Thanks a lot buddy :) - Wish you the best! - Regarding the delete.. try to work it out... I'm tired.. Already up too late (~3AM) :P ... (PS: And I am trying to run away from programming :P)